# Laravel remove public from url in multi project setup

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a server that I intend to use to host multiple projects. So far the structure is like this

```
public_html
- project1
- project2
```

Inside the individual project folders is a Laravel installation. The way I access a project now is http://www.website.com/project1/public

How can I remove that public link from my url? I have tried to set a htaccess file in the root of the project1 but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you want to use different projects for same domain???

Comment: Yeah, Example would be www.website.com/project1 and www.website.com/project2

Comment: I suppose it would be better if you use subdomain to host multiple project.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to restucture how you have put your files on the server.

Firstly you need to have the following

```
project1
project2
public_html
    -project1
    -project2
```

You will install all of your application files in the the root project files. But **do not** put your public folders here e.g.

```
project1
 -app
 -bootstrap
 -(rest of folders)
project2
    -app
    -bootstrap
    -(rest of folders)
public_html
    -project1
    -project2
```

For each project put all of the contents from their respective public folders and put them in the project1 and project2 folders and then remove your public folders. You are basically going to remap the `public_html->project1` and `public_html->project2` folders to be your public folder

You now need to tell laravel where your public folders are by altering the server.php file

change project1/server.php from

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

to

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html/project1'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/project1/index.php';
```

and do the same for `project2`, but use `project2` name instead of `project1`

You should now find that if you go to www.example.com/project1 it should go to the correct project

Comment: Oh wow. I'll try it out and let you know if it works! Thank you!

Comment: At the moment, the public file only has items such as css, js, index.php. Does this mean my view files and controllers go into the root as well?

Comment: No all your resources stay with your laravel installation. The only bit that moves from there is everything out of the public, even the htaccess

Comment: Yeah the only files inside my public folder at the moment are htaccess, favicon, index, robots, css folder and js folder. All my other items are outside the public folder

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this method from this site http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/ and it seems to work for me. Hope this helps the others.